# Repeated Pseudo-Class Selectors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pseudo-class

I noticed in the Bootstrap CSS file:

```
 input:focus:invalid:focus,
 textarea:focus:invalid:focus,
 select:focus:invalid:focus {
   border-color: #e9322d;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
           box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
 s}
```

It appears that :focus is specified twice for input, textarea, and select; does this have a particular function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This increases the css selector's [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

Here is the relevant quote in the `css` specs:

> Note: Repeated occurrences of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity.

So, in this particular case, `input:focus:invalid:focus` will have precedence over `input:focus:invalid`.

Here is a [simpler example](http://jsfiddle.net/QNkcZ/) demonstrating the increase in `css` specificity with repeated occurences:

**css**

```
span.color.color {
    color: green;
}

span.color {
    color: yellow;
}
```

**html**

```
<span class="color">This will be green.</span>
```

Comment: In this case, would input:focus:invalid ever be applied? The block above the given example is:

    `input:focus:invalid,
    textarea:focus:invalid,
    select:focus:invalid {
      color: #b94a48;
      border-color: #ee5f5b;
    }`

Comment: I don't want to say it would never be applied because, TBH, I wouldn't be able to explain the usage in Bootstrap unless it is for commenting out the block above while keeping it in the source... Plus if I am not mistaken this is from BS2.3.2 so it would be difficult to ask today why this was added at the time...